# TokensRegex: Using AND operators

Tags: pattern-matching, stanford-nlp, string-matching

TokensRegex (a module from Standford CoreNLP library) supports & (AND) operators. As I understand, you can use pattern 'X & Y' to match any sequences containing both X and Y. But when I used the operator in real code, it didn't work as the way I expected. Here is my Java code:

```
String content = "data is here and everywhere";
String pattern = "data & is";

TokenizerFactory tf = PTBTokenizer.factory(new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "");
List<CoreLabel> tokens = tf.getTokenizer(new StringReader(content)).tokenize();
TokenSequencePattern seqPattern = TokenSequencePattern.compile(pattern);
TokenSequenceMatcher matcher = seqPattern.getMatcher(tokens);

if(matcher.find()){
      System.out.println("Matched"); // <- I expected to have this printed out
} else {
      System.out.println("Unmatched"); // <- But I've got this instead :(
}
```

Would you please tell me what's wrong with my code or my understanding? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the example given, `matcher.find()` will attempt to find a subsequence in the input token sequence that matches both conditions:

`data`: a sequence of one token with the word `data`

`is`: a sequence of one token with the word `is`

There is obviously no such sequence.  If you want to check if your token sequence include both the word `data` and the word `is`, you can try the pattern:

`String pattern = "(?: ( []* data []* ) & ( []* is []* ))";`

The initial `?:` indicates it doesn't need to do subgroup capturing, and the `[]*` indicates a wildcard for any number of optional tokens.

Although TokensRegex offers AND, it is not really part of normal regular expressions.  It's likely that there are other ways (without the AND) to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your great papers on TokensRegex. So what the reason for you to design AND to operate like that?

If we don't use AND, we may rewrite the pattern as "data []* is | is []* data" right?

Comment: You can rewrite the pattern with the OR (the semantics are a bit different).  The main reason was that it seemed natural for each part of the AND to be a whole sequence.  Also keep in mind that when we are matching tokens, we have other attributes such as the part-of-speech tag, the lemma form, etc that we can match against, so it would like to be used with different attributes.

Comment: I see. Another question about NOT please: For example, I want to match any sequence containing 'Data' but not 'Mr Data'. How can we match for tokens which are not preceded by another specific tokens? 

The rule: "[!{word:Mr}] Data" may work. But it doesn't match sequences like "Data is great", "Data is very  important"....